# use csv file and plot data django2

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-2.0

I have a simple app that import csv file and make plot but without having any error message it doesn't show plot
It's part of my module:

```py
...
def plot_data(self):
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
    return plotly.express.line(df)
...
```

and it's part of my app file:

```py
import panel
def app(doc):
   gspec = pn.GridSpec()
   gspec[0, 1] = pn.Pane(instance_class.plot_data())
   gspec.server_doc(doc)
```

**Update:**

After searching more I could find `HttpResponse` and with that I could write things to csv through using `csv` module but still I have no idea how to read from csv

Also I saw `HttpRequest` and thought maybe I can use it for reading csv but I couldn't find any sample code and couldn't understand documentation about using it as a reader

Comment: did you execute `app(some_document)`? And maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in all variables. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: @furas thank you, yes I did it exactly and figured out I'm not able to pass pandas line, even I tried with csv module of python that fail as well